# If $a$ is divisible by $4$, then there exist int $b$ and $c$ such that $a = b^2 - c^2$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

I want to prove this:

Prove that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ is divisible by $4$, then there exist $b$ and $c$ where $b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a = b^2 - c^2$

I want to prove this directily:

$4\mid a $,  $a\in \mathbb{Z} \implies \exists b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad$ s.t. $a=b^2-c^2$

Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $4=a\cdot k$ and $k$ can divide $4$. Hence,

$\frac{4}{k} =b^2 - c^2 = (b-c)(b+c) \implies \dfrac{4}{k\cdot(b-c)} = b+c$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: $4=ak$ is wrong. If $4$ divides $a$ means that there is some $k$ such that $4k=a$. And $\frac{4}{k*(b-c)=b+c}$ doesn't even make any sense. **Hint:** Suppose you arbitrarily decide that $b=c+2$ ...?

Comment: The proof is not correct, note that you have swapped $k$ and $4$ in $4=a*k$, which should be $4k=a$.  But this is not a direction that would be helpful in proving this theorem.

Comment: Thx for your answers!!!

Comment: Please check if my edits are what you intended, particularly the second last line.

Comment: There are too many logical symbols. The $4=ak$ is incorrect, we could have $a=12$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a=4k$ then $a=4k=(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint. If $a=b^2-c^2$, then $a=(b+c)(b-c)$

Suppose $a=pq$ with $p\gt q$ try $a+b=p$ and $a-b=q$ and solve for $a,b$

Now relate that to the other facts you know about $a$ to conclude.